# trying to pass a % into my calculation app but it's coming up as NaN

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an app that's supposed to make a calculation but when I try to subtract from the sum total with a % value like '2.9%' my sum total ends up being NaN

I can't figure it out

```
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       soldPrice: 0,
       shippingCost: 0,
       shippingCharge: 0,
       itemCost: 0,
       profit: 0,
       paypalFeePercentage: '2.9%',
       paypalFee: 0.30,
       ebayFee: '10%'
     };
  }

  calculateProfit = () => {
    const { soldPrice, shippingCost, shippingCharge, itemCost,
      paypalFeePercentage, paypalFee, ebayFee
     } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      profit: Number(soldPrice) - Number(shippingCost) + Number(shippingCharge) -
      Number(itemCost) - Number(paypalFeePercentage) - Number(ebayFee)
      - Number(paypalFee)
    });
  }
```

I'm expecting the final sum but instead I'm getting NaN

Comment: you can pass a function that returns the result instead of passing a string "2.9%".

Comment: `Number('2.9%')` and `Number('10%')` are both `NaN`. You'll need to write a parsing method that handles percent strings

Comment: How would I write that parsing methoud

Comment: Think about what "percent" means; per cent; every 100. So you want to subtract 2.9 dollars for every 100 dollars, or as it is most commonly done, multiply the total by 0.029 and subtract that value. If you prefer video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRmiUD2nflA

Answer (score 2):

You're getting NaN because they are strings, not numbers. Change `paypalFeePercentage` and `ebayFee` to numbers:

```
this.state = {
   soldPrice: 0,
   shippingCost: 0,
   shippingCharge: 0,
   itemCost: 0,
   profit: 0,
   paypalFeePercentage: 0.029,
   paypalFee: 0.30,
   ebayFee: 0.1
 };
```

In order to subtract 10% of the sold fee, you just need to do some more math. Instead of passing your calculations through setState, I'd recommend setting it to a variable that you pass to state.

```
calculateProfit = () => {
    const { soldPrice, shippingCost, shippingCharge, itemCost,
      paypalFeePercentage, paypalFee, ebayFee
     } = this.state;

  let calculation = soldPrice - shippingCost + shippingCharge - itemCost - 
      payPalFeePercentage - soldprice*ebayFee

    this.setState({
      profit: calculation
    });
  }
```

Comment: that would work if i wanted to minus only 0.1 but im trying to minus ten percent of the whole sum

Comment: You're trying to subtract 10% of the sold price?

Comment: See updated answer. Basically you just need to do some more math.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to memorise balance equation in natural way.

```
paypalFee / soldPrice = Percentage / 100
```

---

usually You have one variable missing, in this case it is paypalFee. I am assuming that solid price is x

```
paypalFee / x = 2.9 / 100
```

then you have high school math (proportion) to multiple outer from both sides and inner from both sides.

```
paypalFee * 100 = 2.9 * x

paypalFee = 2.9 * x /100
```

It works the same in all languages and on paper. JavaScript is no exception.